# Semantic versioning : Incrementing by two

Tags: semantic-versioning

Had a question related to Semantic Version

We have two levels of customers - Levels 1 & 2. We have a current release (Say 1.0.2). We did a release for Level 1 with a minor number change (1.0.3) - but then decided that it will not go to Level 2. Now the next release should go to both Levels 1 & 2. But if we release it with 1.0.4 then it will look like a skip for Level 2 users. If we stick with 1.0.3, it will conflict with our Level 1 users.

So, for from a Level 2 users point of view, Would it be strictly consistent with Semantic Version if we skip a version number?

Any links could help. Thanks.

Comment: Well they *are* two different versions, so there's not much to argue about IMO. And increasing a minor number by more than one is not uncommon for just about any project, commercial or not.

Answer (score 0):

It's just fine to skip a version number.